# How state variable is updated after deleting a record in the DB?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and I have the following code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Users() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/show")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setUsers(data));
  }, [users]);

  function deleteUser(id) {
    axios.delete(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/delete/${id}`);
  }
  const showUsers = users.map((user, index) => (
    <tr key={index}>
      <td>{index + 1}</td>
      <td>{user.name}</td>
      <td>{user.email}</td>
      <td>
        <Link to={`${user.id}`}>
          <i
            className="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"
            style={{ paddingRight: "10px", cursor: "pointer" }}
          ></i>
        </Link>
        <i
          className="fa-solid fa-trash"
          style={{ color: "red", cursor: "pointer" }}
          onClick={() => deleteUser(user.id)}
        ></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ));
  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{showUsers}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I delete a user, using the `deleteUser` function, the `users` array is updated which in turn re-renders the component. I am really confused! how the `users` array is updated although I am not using `setUser` in `deleteUser` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not updated by `deleteUser`.

Instead, your component is probably repeatedly calling the API because `users` is a dependency for the effect that sets `users` with `setUsers`. (Look at your browser's network inspector to see if this is happening.)

Comment: Thanks bro! It's just like what you have said!

Comment: what do you suggest to solve this problem? I want the component to re-rendered whenever I delete a user.

Comment: Move the innards of your effect into a function in the component, then call that function after your deletion succeeds. Alternately, use e.g. [swr](https://swr.vercel.app/) for your data fetching and call its `mutate` function.